# I don't exist yet. Help me fix that!

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

At the time of this posting, I don't exist.  You can help fix that, though.  In fact, the author posits that if you're reading this, you've probably done something similar enough already.

That doesn't make your task any less delicate, however -- if you don't help me in just the right way you'll create something that *looks* like me, but actually isn't.  Whether or not you actually manage to help me, you'll pick not-quite-me apart to try to convince yourself that you did.  Don't let that discourage you, though; you still get props for trying.

There's (hopefully) only one way that you can bring me into existence.  But the author and I promise, if you do then your success will stand high above the rest, and be made obvious for all to see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> This answer

At the time of this posting, I don't exist

> It wasn't here when you posted the question.

You can help fix that, though

> I just fixed that

you don't help me in just the right way you'll create something that looks like me... you'll pick not-quite-me apart to try to convince yourself that you did

> I might be wrong, making arguments that are lopsided.

There's (hopefully) only one way that you can bring me into existence

> Some questions may have more than one answer, but here we should be posting riddles, which have one right answer.

if you do then your success will stand high above the rest, and be made obvious for all to see

> This answer will be marked as the correct one and will pop up against the rest,if there will be any others.

Comment: I was typing it.

Comment: Oh, wow, this was a lot faster than I thought.  Good job!

Answer (score 1):

#### This is not the intended answer(my achievement)...confirmed by OP

I think it is

> Question

---

**Explanation**

---

At the time of this posting, I don't exist.

> There is no question in the whole riddle.

You can help fix that, though.

> As the riddle's answer is 'question' so it is fixed.

In fact, the author posits that if you're reading this, you've probably done something similar enough already.

> If we read a puzzle, we assume that there must be a question.

That doesn't make your task any less delicate, however -- if you don't help me in just the right way you'll create something that looks like me, but actually isn't.

> If we are wrong then we'll create an answer which will not be a question.

Whether or not you actually manage to help me, you'll pick me apart to try to convince yourself that you did. Don't let that discourage you, though; you still get props for trying.

> We try to pick what is the question in the riddle.

There's (hopefully) only one way that you can bring me into existence. But I promise, if you do then your success will stand high above the rest, and be made obvious for all to see.

> As the answer is 'question', so now it exists.

Comment: You're on the right track, but nope!  (I'm new here, is it acceptable etiquette for me to tell you that?)

Comment: @JesseTG yeah that's acceptable and normal thing to do..